# How to retrieve existing indexes on tables in SQL Server using code?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, ado.net, indexing

We are using NHibernate with SQL Server for our backend. I want to retrieve the list of all indexes on a few of my tables programmatically. Is there a way to do this using NHibernate or even ADO.Net?

I can query the sys tables to get this info but was wondering if there are any APIs for this.

Searching has not really returned any concrete solutions. If anyone else has done something similar, what were your findings and your final approach?

Any suggestions or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `sys` catalog views (or the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views) **ARE** the API ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API for this in either ADO.NET or NHibernate because this is a highly implementation specific construct and some platforms you might use NHibernate or ADO.NET with do not have this concept at all.  ADO.NET and NHibernate are abstractions, and, as such, they are going to hide things (or not even use some features) in the interest of presenting a general interface.

If you want a .NET API to SQL Server metadata, the thing to look at would be [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.table.indexes.aspx) (which has a Table object with an Indexes property) - this is part of the Microsoft.SqlServer namespace (not System.Data).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Cade. SMO looks promising and provides me with all the data I need.
Do you have any general comments about using SMO in production code?

Comment: @Nitesh Baranwal - I'm not big on using SMO - frankly it's too low level, and I like my app to perceive a very clear database perimeter - and that usually means hiding table implementation.  Typically I like to have procs which query (and join) the various metadata all in the database engine and then call those procs just like other application procs.  I use metadata a lot for code generation and system maintenance and write a lot of that code in SQL and then connect to it like any other application/client code.

Answer (score 3):

```
select  *
from    sys.indexes
where   object_id = object_id('YourTable')
```

Comment: Andomar, thanks for the query. This is my last resort but right now I want to know if there are any APIs for this in NHibernate or ADO.Net

Comment: @Nitesh Baranwal: What would be the point of such an API when you can just query the information?

Answer (score 0):

Check the INFORMATION_SCHEMA - it contains, in every databas, a significant numer of views taht give you a lot of interesting information about all the objects in the database.